# Why is it not in the order of key when converting key to uppercase even though I use LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

When I convert to lowercase, it's in the right order.
When I try to convert to uppercase,it's wrong.
I try to use LinkedHashMap to keeping the insertion order.
I think stream changed the order of keys,But I don't know how to sort after changing the key.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    static List<Map<String,Object>>  convertKeyCase (List<Map<String,Object>> list,int...s) {

       return list.stream().map(m -> m.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> s.length == 0 || s[0]==1 ? p.getKey().toUpperCase():p.getKey().toLowerCase(), Map.Entry::getValue)))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String,Object>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<String,Object> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String,Object> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();


        map1.put("date","2021-06-03");
        map1.put("weather","1");
        map1.put("wind","2-3");
        map1.put("temp","17-29°C");
        list1.add(map1);

        map2.put("date","2021-06-04");
        map2.put("weather","1");
        map2.put("wind","3-4");
        map2.put("temp","17-30°C");
        list1.add(map2);

        List<Map<String,Object>> list = convertKeyCase(list1);
        List<Map<String,Object>> list2 = convertKeyCase(list1,0);
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(list2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Read the API -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the input `List` contains `LinkedHashMap`s doesn't mean that the output will contain `LinkedHashMap`s.

If you want `LinkedHashMap`s, you must request them explicitly in the `toMap()` call:

```
static List<Map<String,Object>>  convertKeyCase (List<Map<String,Object>> list,int...s) {

   return list.stream()
              .map(m -> m.entrySet()
                         .stream()
                         .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> s.length == 0 || s[0]==1 ? p.getKey().toUpperCase():p.getKey().toLowerCase(),
                                                   Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                   (v1,v2)->v1,
                                                   LinkedHashMap::new)))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

This changes the output to:

```
[{DATE=2021-06-03, TEMP=17-29°C, WEATHER=1, WIND=2-3}, {DATE=2021-06-04, TEMP=17-30°C, WEATHER=1, WIND=3-4}]
[{date=2021-06-03, temp=17-29°C, weather=1, wind=2-3}, {date=2021-06-04, temp=17-30°C, weather=1, wind=3-4}]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely,i understand.
excuse me, if I use hashmap, can I sort?

Comment: @OldLetter HashMap has no ordering, so the sorting of the stream will be lost once you collect into a HashMap. LinkedHashMap, on the other hand, preserves insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

After below two lines again you will get a `List` and natural sorting will be applied. You have to change your implementation to return `LinkedHashMap`  there.

```
    List<Map<String,Object>> list = convertKeyCase(list1);
    List<Map<String,Object>> list2 = convertKeyCase(list1,0);
```